# Hash Partitioning RDF (OWL/N3/NT) datasets

Tags: hash, rdf, owl, nt, n3

I have an N3 dataset that contains triples. I wish to hash partition this dataset. Is there a hash partitioner that hash partitions OWL/NT/N3 datasets? If not, could you please provide me with some code/tips on how to proceed with parsing the file in an effective way.

Comment: Reasons for closing questions include "Questions asking for code must demonstrate a minimal understanding of the problem being solved. Include attempted solutions, why they didn't work, and the expected results."  What sort of things have you tried so far?  Parsing the file is an entirely different task from storing the resulting triples in an efficient way.  As to "parsing the file in an effective way", I typically use one of the many RDF processing libraries out there, and that works just fine.  Can you clarify what you're _actually_ trying to do, and what hasn't worked about it so far?

Comment: Thanks for explaining the protocol here. I generated an OWL dataset using LUBM's (Lehigh University Benchmak) data generator, and converted it to N3 format using an online converter. Now, I would like to hash partition the dataset and store each partition on a worker machine. Before implementing my own, I wanted to know if there is such a library out there. Could you please point me to some of the available libraries. As for efficiency, I mentioned it because the dataset I have is very large and using a sequential hash partitioner might consume a lot of time to finish the task.

Comment: First, OWL is not the same as RDF, but OWL can be serialized in RDF.  Second, RDF can be serialized in a number of forms.  One of the most common is RDF/XML, but there are also N3, Turtle (a subset of N3), and N-Triples (NT).  N-Triples is a line based format.  If you just need to split your data into three pieces and send it places, just convert it into N-triples.  It will have k lines.  Send the first k/3 to A, the second k/3 to B, and the last k/3 to B. Or you could iterate through through the lines one at a time, sending a line to A, then a line to B, then a line to C.

Comment: One of the big advantages of N-Triples is that it's line based, so it's _very_ cheap to split or combine datasets.  Is this the sort of thing you were looking for?  If it is, I can write it up in an answer.

Comment: Thanks for the clarifications...Can you please point out some of the available libraries just for future reference.

Comment: @NewToAndroid as for which tools: there is tons of 'm depending on taste, programming environment. A simple Google search should give you ample starting points, or have a look here at some related questions, like http://stackoverflow.com/questions/73445/what-are-some-good-java-rdf-libraries

Answer (score 2):

Parsing an RDF file is an entirely different task from storing the resulting triples in an efficient way. For simply *parsing* the RDF file, you can use one of the many RDF processing libraries out there, and that works just fine. (StackOverflow really  isn't the place for lists of tools, but the question [Which Tools and Libraries do you use to develop Semantic Web applications?](http://answers.semanticweb.com/questions/75/which-tools-and-libraries-do-you-use-to-develop-semantic-web-applications) on http://answers.semanticweb.com has a bunch listed.)  As you clarified in the comments:

> I generated an OWL dataset using LUBM's (Lehigh University Benchmak)
>   data generator, and converted it to N3 format using an online
>   converter. Now, I would like to hash partition the dataset and store
>   each partition on a worker machine. Before implementing my own, I
>   wanted to know if there is such a library out there. Could you please
>   point me to some of the available libraries. As for efficiency, I
>   mentioned it because the dataset I have is very large and using a
>   sequential hash partitioner might consume a lot of time to finish the
>   task.

There are at least two importan things to note here.

1. OWL is not the same as RDF, but OWL can be *serialized* in RDF. It appears that you've already serialized your OWL in RDF.
2. RDF can be serialized in a number of forms. One of the most common is RDF/XML, but there are also N3, Turtle (a subset of N3), and N-Triples (NT).

N-Triples is a line-based format, with just one triple per line. If you just need to split your data into three pieces and send it places, just convert it into N-triples, where the *k* triples will be on *k* lines. You could then send the first *k/3* to worker A, the second *k/3* to worker B, and the last *k/3* to worker B. Alternatively, you could iterate through through the lines one at a time, sending a line to A, then a line to B, then a line to C.  This is one of the big advantages of N-Triples: it's very cheap to split or combine datasets.  As an example, consider this DBpedia query and [its results in NTriples](http://dbpedia.org/sparql?default-graph-uri=http://dbpedia.org&query=construct%20where%20%7B%20%0D%0A%20%20dbpedia%3aMount_Monadnock%20?prop%20?obj%0D%0A%7D%0D%0Alimit%2010%20&format=text/plain&timeout=30000&debug=on). You can just split it up into three chunks of 3, 3, and 4 lines, and send them off to your workers.

```
construct where { 
  dbpedia:Mount_Monadnock ?prop ?obj
}
limit 10
```

```
<http://dbpedia.org/resource/Mount_Monadnock>   <http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#type>   <http://schema.org/Mountain> .
<http://dbpedia.org/resource/Mount_Monadnock>   <http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#type>   <http://dbpedia.org/ontology/NaturalPlace> .
<http://dbpedia.org/resource/Mount_Monadnock>   <http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#type>   <http://www.opengis.net/gml/_Feature> .
<http://dbpedia.org/resource/Mount_Monadnock>   <http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#type>   <http://dbpedia.org/class/yago/GeologicalFormation109287968> .
<http://dbpedia.org/resource/Mount_Monadnock>   <http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#type>   <http://umbel.org/umbel/rc/Mountain> .
<http://dbpedia.org/resource/Mount_Monadnock>   <http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#type>   <http://dbpedia.org/ontology/Mountain> .
<http://dbpedia.org/resource/Mount_Monadnock>   <http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#type>   <http://dbpedia.org/ontology/Place> .
<http://dbpedia.org/resource/Mount_Monadnock>   <http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#type>   <http://dbpedia.org/class/yago/Object100002684> .
<http://dbpedia.org/resource/Mount_Monadnock>   <http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#type>   <http://schema.org/Place> .
<http://dbpedia.org/resource/Mount_Monadnock>   <http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#type>   <http://www.w3.org/2002/07/owl#Thing> .
```